# Unrecognizable Lambda Output Cognito

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I am trying to implement an auto confirm mechanism in AWS, I'm getting an error due to the Lambda response. I can't find the correct return type in the docs.

Lambda:

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    event.response.autoConfirmUser = true;
    context.succeed(event.response);
};
```

Exception:

> Unrecognizable lambda output (Service:
>   AWSCognitoIdentityProviderService; Status Code: 400; Error Code:
>   InvalidLambdaResponseException; Request ID:
>   5c7a2436-0515-11e7-b971-41a89adf53ea)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

As shown in the [PreSignUp trigger example](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-identity-pools-working-with-aws-lambda-triggers.html#aws-lambda-triggers-pre-registration-example) in Cognito developer guide, you should use `context.done(null, event);` or `context.succeed(event);` at the end of your trigger.

Cognito expects the complete event source back in response from your lambda triggers being invoked as part of different Cognito User Pools flows.

Comment: @Chetan What would be the equivalent in Java?

Comment: @Chetan, Is there an example for this in Java?

Comment: I need help on this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49002115/unrecognizable-lambda-output-aws-cognito-in-swift

Comment: what is equivalent in dotnet core ?

Comment: I am getting this error in a api call - where my lambda is supposed to change the Forgotten Password - and I am using Java sdk - please help

Answer (score 11):

Ruby lambda people, all cognito wants back is the event object.

```js
def lambda_handler(event:, context:)
    # TODO implement
    return event
end
```

Comment: Same with python.

Comment: Any idea about how to pass back an error message? I'm using python and returning the event works to signal success, but not sure how to pass back an error message.  Any change to the event leads to an "Unrecognizable lambda output" error. *I'm using the Cognito hosted UI option and that's why it's important for me to pass back a meaningful error message that is displayed on the sign-up page. @BLang

Comment: @Stasv See my answer to your question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50661422/denying-a-sign-up-request-in-cognito-user-pools/54001259#54001259

Answer (score 4):

Is very simple.

1. Create a Lambda Function with this code : [example](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-identity-pools-working-with-aws-lambda-triggers.html#aws-lambda-triggers-pre-registration-example)

   ```
   exports.handler = function(event, context) {

   /* This Lambda function returns a flag to indicate if a user should be auto-confirmed.
   Perform any necessary validations.Impose a condition that the minimum length of the
   username of 5 is imposed on all user pools. */

      if (event.userName.length < 5) {
         var error = new Error('failed!');
         context.done(error, event);
      }

   /* Access your resource which contains the list of emails of users who were invited to
   sign up. Compare the list of email IDs from the request to the approved list */

      if(event.userPoolId === "yourSpecialUserPool") {
         if (event.request.userAttributes.email in listOfEmailsInvited) {
              event.response.autoConfirmUser = true;
         }
      }

      // Return result to Cognito
      context.done(null, event);
   };
   ```

Note: Role: Lambda basic execution

2. Create the trigger from cognito console and select the function lambda.

TEST
3. Create the user with the API and DONE.

Answer (score 1):

In 2022, seems like the docs have been updated such that `callback(null, event);` is needed for successful **login**. as such this will accept and log to cloudwatch.

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

    // Send post authentication data to Cloudwatch logs
    console.log ("Authentication successful");
    console.log ("Trigger function =", event.triggerSource);
    console.log ("User pool = ", event.userPoolId);
    console.log ("App client ID = ", event.callerContext.clientId);
    console.log ("User ID = ", event.userName);

    // Return to Amazon Cognito
    callback(null, event);
};
```

Source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-post-authentication.html

Comment: definitely not working, despite being from docs.