# Denying a Sign-up request in Cognito User Pools

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

The description of a Cognito User Pools Pre Sign-up Lambda Trigger is:

> This trigger is invoked when a user submits their information to sign up, allowing you to perform custom validation to accept or deny the sign up request.

I want to deny a sign-up request based on a certain condition in my Lambda. The trigger parameters (reproduced from the docs below) seem to only support auto-verification and auto-confirmation:

```
{
    "request": {
        "userAttributes": {
            "string": "string",
            ....
        },
        "validationData": {
            "string": "string",
            "string": "string",
             ....
        }
    },

    "response": {
        "autoConfirmUser": "boolean",
        "autoVerifyPhone": "boolean",
        "autoVerifyEmail": "boolean"
    }
}
```

How can I accept or deny a sign-up request based on the outcome of the Pre Sign-up Lambda Trigger?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can deny signup by throwing an exception, as shown [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-pre-authentication.html#aws-lambda-triggers-pre-authentication-example).

The exception message will be passed back to Cognito, and on to the client, in the form of a validation error with the message `PreSignUp failed with error {exceptionMessage}.`.

Comment: This used to be the case, and was very useful for us to pass back information to the frontend for the user to make decisions and act on, e.g. do you want to link your Google sign in with an existing user profile? But, at least as of the current date and with the latest version of AWS Amplify, this no longer works as far as I can tell, and you always get back a generic, "Exception processing authorization code" in the error_description query parameter. Very frustrating indeed.

Comment: No, I don't think causing the lambda to error should be considered the correct answer, but rather a workaround. This isn't desirable, if, for example, you have monitoring on lambdas, with an error indicating that something needs to be investigated and/or fixed. Denying a user sign-up based on business rules is a non-exceptional event and happens all the time. It's more analogous to a 400 HTTP response than a 500 HTTP response. Plus the inability to have full control over the error message renders this method a bit clunky.

Comment: Note that rejecting signups via exception like this causes them to show up in cloudwatch logs and metrics as 'ERROR', which may or may not be desirable

Comment: This still works as of today using Node 12. Whether denying a user sign up based on some parameters they entered is an error or not may be a matter of opinion, but currently this appears to be the cleanest way to accomplish this which provides meaningful feedback to the user. As opposed to returning null which gives the user a meaningless error

Comment: Works fine using Python 3.7, and according to the official documentation. To me this should be the accepted answer as long as AWS doesn't provide a cleaner way to do this.

Answer (score 11):

You can return a empty dict from the lambda to deny sign up request. Similarly you return the event value itself to accept the sign up request.

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    if denySignUp:
        return {}
    else:
        return event
```

Comment: I would add that in the Node environment, where the function signature is `exports.handler = (event, context, callback) =>`, you can deny the request with `callback({})` and accept with `callback(null, event)`.

Comment: What if you want to specify a specific rejection type or error message?

Comment: @sfdz Denying the request using `callback({})` for node environments is actually [treated the same as throwing an exception](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-handler.html) (and hence corresponds more to Grejdi's answer than this one). Returning an empty object in Node env would be `callback(null, {})`, which doesn't deny a sign-up request for me, but instead gives me a `Invalid version. Version should be 1` error. This leads me to believe that returning an empty object to deny a sign-up without error-ing the lambda is not actually supported.

Comment: This is obviously a legitimate (and non-exceptional) use-case, but has Amazon even acknowledged it as legit?

Comment: This no longer works as you might expect. Returning `{}` is now an error: `Invalid version. Version should be 1`. So while this will still deny the sign up, your error logs will be full of these errors. At least if you raise your own exception, you can fill up your error logs with a meaningless error of your choosing ;)

Comment: Is there a way to remove the prefix "PreSignUp failed with error" from the error message?