# Deny a Sign-up request in Cognito User Pools using NETCore 2.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

The description of a Cognito User Pools Pre Sign-up Lambda Trigger is:

> This trigger is invoked when a user submits their information to sign up, allowing you to perform custom validation to accept or deny the sign up request.

I want to deny a sign-up request based on a certain condition in my Lambda. The trigger parameters (reproduced from the docs below) seem to only support auto-verification and auto-confirmation:

```
{
    "request": {
        "userAttributes": {
            "string": "string",
            ....
        },
        "validationData": {
            "string": "string",
            "string": "string",
             ....
        }
    },

    "response": {
        "autoConfirmUser": "boolean",
        "autoVerifyPhone": "boolean",
        "autoVerifyEmail": "boolean"
    }
}
```

How can I accept or deny a sign-up request based on the outcome of the Pre Sign-up Lambda Trigger on C# (NETCore)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Denying a Sign-up request in Cognito User Pools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50661422/denying-a-sign-up-request-in-cognito-user-pools)

Comment: I need it in C# and in that one is for Node or Python